# Could a raspberry pi run Quartus?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I'm fairly new to unix/raspberry pi. As a part of a research project I'm required to program and read data off a frontend board (connected to some pixel sensors) using a 'usb blaster' JTAG connection. Unfortunately i cannot do this with the linux computer i was supposed to since sudo priveleges are necessary and I cannot be granted them. I was wondering if it was possible to install quartus on a raspberry pi since it runs linux,allowing access to the frontend board? Sorry if this is not a relevant question

Comment: sudo privileges are NOT necessary.  figure out what privileges you specifically need.  it may be a common group feature like the dialout for tty, it may be read/write to specific "files" (user permissions model) or to run a specific approved executable and only that executable with elevated or even outright kernel permissions (the driver model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry; Quartus does not run on the Pi (or any ARM for that matter).

A project to use a Raspberry Pi Zero (or Zero W) as a replacement for the Altera "USB Blaster" chip programmer [(see the READ.ME)](https://github.com/Memotech-Bill/Blaster_Gadget/blob/master/README.md) has officially given up.

So, I guess, you're out of luck.

You should look at the permissions that you really need on the original Linux system. Of course, with `sudo` you don't have any permission problems, but `root` is not always required for accessing USB devices.